# Cascading ACL to embedded objects

Tags: database-design, security, permissions

We have an object Root, which references many other objects. Which eventually is translated into FKs on the DB level. We came up with an ACL scheme where there's a separate `permissions` table with the `user,resource,access_level`. And so we change our logic to look at this table before returning the data to the user.

Problem is, objects that are nested should also have the same permissions. And so there are 2 solutions that I could think of:

1. Each nested object is written into `permissions`. Every time we update Root object, we cascade the changes to all nested ones.
2. We add `root_id` to all relevant tables (even if they are referenced through some other intermediate object). And keep checking permissions using this `root_id`.

Both approaches aren't easy to implement. So I wonder maybe there are other approaches that I'm missing.

Comment: Can you clarify two things: 1) what does ACL mean to you? 2) What is the use case?

Comment: ACL is a list of permissions (READ/WRITE) that are granted to a list of users (SID) on some objects (OID). So the use case is: user creates an object and then he wants to list what other users can see/modify that object.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth looking into (the principles of) OpenFGA. I just stumbled on to it myself but it seems a powerful method/tool that might fit your needs.

Comment: @Sil, OpenFGA eventually references this paper: https://research.google/pubs/pub48190/ which seems to be quite relevant. Will read it soon, thanks!